# Regex to get all character to the right of first # and left of first space?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to keep `456` with a regex from the following string:

```
jo​hn​#456 18 mai 2017 11:01
```

I tested with

```
#(.*)
```

But I keep `456 18 mai 2017`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex, that will extract the number after your `#`:

```
.+#(\d+ )
```

Tested on the following data:

```
 jo​hn​#456 18 mai 2017 11:01
test123#123 18 mai 2017 11:01
michael#4561218 mai 2017 11:01
'(çà'_(fdlfsnd#456 18 mai 2017 11:01
lrjdlfddfdf#456 18 mai 2017 11:01
```

The regex extracts:

```
456
123
4561218
465
465
```

#### [Here is a demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1r22oS/2)

Javascript solution:

```js
const regex4id = /.+#(\d+)/g;
var text = "jo​hn​#456 18 mai 2017 11:01"
var id =  text.match(regex4id);
if(id != null) {
    p = regex4id.exec(text);
    console.log("p: " + p[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Lookahead and Lookbehind:**

To get left of # and before the next space, you could also use a positive lookbehind and lookahead if you wanted it as a full match without using capturing groups:

```
(?<=#)\w+(?=\s)
```

- `(?<=#)` is a positive lookbehind which ensures that `#` preceeds the match
- `\w+` matches one or more characters (includes alphabets, numbers and underscore)
- `(?=\s)` is a positive lookahead which ensures that a space `\s` follows the match

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0tA8Jc/1/)

Learn more about [lookaheads and lookbehinds here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups).

**Using a capturing group:**

You can also do it faster using a capturing group instead of lookaheads and lookbehinds. (Though the difference is negligible when only performing it for one match)

```
#(\w+)\s
```

Here, you can extract it by referring to group 1 based on your language `$1` or `group[1]`

- `#` represents literal `#`
- `(\w+)` represents one or more characters in a capturing group (which is the 1st capturing group
- `\s` represents  a single space

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5FzXUa/1/)

Hope this helps!